# Video timeline dragging and click

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, gsap

I am new to GSAP and I am trying to enable dragging and click on custom html5 video timeline with GSAP. I have read a couple of posts on the GSAP forum but there is something I obviously can't understand...

I've reproduced a simplified example on the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/epigeyre/oLmk6b0d/2/

So I create my draggable element from an element stored in a variable, bound it to it's container (which is the timeline container), and then add my function onDrag (I guess click will be the same). The timeline progress is shown by a div inside the timeline container that is scaling on an X axis from 0 to 1. I think linking to the current video time is ok but the animation is not (I don't understand why a translate is applied...).

Here is that specific snippet:

```
Draggable.create( timelineProgress, {
  type:'x',
  bounds: timeline, // My timeline container
  onDrag: function() {
    video.currentTime = this.x / this.maxX * video.duration;
    TweenLite.set( timelineProgress, { scaleX: this.x / this.maxX } ) ;
  },
  onClick: function() {
    video.currentTime = this.x / this.maxX * video.duration;
    TweenLite.set( timelineProgress, { scaleX: this.x / this.maxX } ) ;
  }
});
```

Could you help me understand what's going?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. The draggable does work if you remove the various lines that cause the scaleX of TimelineProgress to change. What are you trying to achieve with scaleX? I think there is an update property of draggable that may help if scaleX needs to remain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've found a solution using the `trigger` property. I'll post my code here when I have a bit of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so here the solution for those in need of building a custom video player. Using GSAP you have a really interesting `trigger` property within the Draggable plugin.

Here is how I made it work for an HTML5 video timeline.

```js
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0],
    play = document.getElementsByClassName('video__play')[0],
    timeline = document.getElementsByClassName('timeline')[0],
    timelineProgress = document.getElementsByClassName('timeline__progress')[0],
    drag = document.getElementsByClassName('timeline__drag')[0];

// Toggle Play / Pause
play.addEventListener('click', togglePlay, false);

function togglePlay() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }
}

// on interaction with video controls
video.onplay = function() {
  TweenMax.ticker.addEventListener('tick', vidUpdate);
};
video.onpause = function() {
 TweenMax.ticker.removeEventListener('tick', vidUpdate);
};
video.onended = function() {
 TweenMax.ticker.removeEventListener('tick', vidUpdate);
};

// Sync the timeline with the video duration
function vidUpdate() {
  TweenMax.set(timelineProgress, {
    scaleX: (video.currentTime / video.duration).toFixed(5)
  });
  TweenMax.set(drag, {
    x: (video.currentTime / video.duration * timeline.offsetWidth).toFixed(4)
  });
}

// Make the timeline draggable
Draggable.create(drag, {
  type: 'x',
  trigger: timeline,
  bounds: timeline,
  onPress: function(e) {
    video.currentTime = this.x / this.maxX * video.duration;
    TweenMax.set(this.target, {
      x: this.pointerX - timeline.getBoundingClientRect().left
    });
    this.update();
    var progress = this.x / timeline.offsetWidth;
    TweenMax.set(timelineProgress, {
      scaleX: progress
    });
  },
  onDrag: function() {
    video.currentTime = this.x / this.maxX * video.duration;
    var progress = this.x / timeline.offsetWidth;
    TweenMax.set(timelineProgress, {
      scaleX: progress
    });
  },
  onRelease: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.timeline {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

/* Here is the dragger that I will use to move the video 
* current time forward or backward.
* I have added a background color for you to see it
* but just remove it in production.
*/

.timeline__drag {
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.timeline__progress {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

button {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.0/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<video>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline__drag"></div>
  <span class="timeline__progress"></span>
</div>
<button class="video__play">Play / Pause video</button>
```

I have to thanks Carl of the GSAP forum for his wonderful help!